# Mule Custom Exception Class not catching some exceptions

Tags: exception, mule

I have a Mule flow which obtains an oauth token from a service which may throw a fault. However the exception is not caught in the flow even though there is a catch exception strategy at the end. Can someone explain why the exception is not caught? When I post XML via SOAP UI using an invalid token to trigger an exception, the request gets to the flow, but the exception is not caught. Instead I get a stack trace indicating an invalid token. Here is the flow:

```
    <flow name="order-query">
      <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_config"
          path="order/request" doc:name="HTTP" />
       <flow-ref name="oauth-token-service">
      <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="SPOP SOAP"
            serviceClass="o.x.p.SpopWS">
          <cxf:inInterceptors>
            <spring:ref bean="HeaderInInterceptor" />
        </cxf:inInterceptors>
        <cxf:outInterceptors>
            <spring:ref bean="faultOutInterceptor" />
            <spring:ref bean="headerOutInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outInterceptors>
        <cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
            <spring:ref bean="OutSoapFaultInterceptor" />
        </cxf:outFaultInterceptors>
    </cxf:jaxws-service>
    <scripting:transformer>
        <scripting:script engine="python">
           ...
        </scripting:script>
    <scripting:transformer>
    <catch-exception-strategy>
       <logger level="INFO" message=" Should be handled here #[payload]"/>
    </catch-exception-strategy>
  </flow>
```

Comment: The logger statement in the catch is not printed.  I do not see the message "Should be handled here... " anywhere in the logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure the exception is not catched? the default behavior of catch-exception-strategy is to log the catched exception. This is the reason why you see the stack trace in logs.

**for mule 3.8 and above:** you can disable/enable this behavior either with a checkbox (*Log Exceptions*):

[image]

or in XML (`logException=false`):

```
<catch-exception-strategy logException="false" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</catch-exception-strategy>
```

**for mule 3.7:** take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42181054/804521

Comment: I am using version 3.7.3. I get: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'logException' is not allowed to appear in element 'catch-exception-strategy'.

Comment: hmm... according to [documentation](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/catch-exception-strategy#configcatchstrat) `Log Exceptions` is supported by 3.7 (though no xml-example in documentation).

Comment: but you are right, i can see the error message too, when i switch my runtime from 3.8 to 3.7

Comment: The logException is not implemented in 3.7.3 it turns out as  I found out from another link.  I am trying to use set the logger attributes to see if that will suppress the errors.